# How to enable the `JSON1` extension for `SQLite3` in PHP?

Tags: php, dll, sqlite, sqlite-json1

I want to try the [`JSON1`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) extension for SQLite in PHP7 but it is not enabled by default.

So I have compiled a new `php_sqlite3.dll` with the `JSON1` extension enabled as per these [instructions](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#compiling_the_json1_extension) but when I try to start PHP I get an error;

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'sqlite3'
in Unknown on line 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

### Further info

After replacing `php_sqlite3.dll` with my version, the `SQLite3` class no longer works in PHP eg. this line of PHP code;

```
$cn = new SQLite3(':memory:');
```

gives this error;

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SQLite3' not found
```

I compiled the new `php_sqlite3.dll` by doing;

```
gcc -g -shared -DSQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1 sqlite3.c -o php_sqlite3.dll
```

Then I replaced `php_sqlite3.dll` in my Windows PHP `/ext` folder with the one created above.

Answer (score 2):

The `php_sqlite3.dll` library is a library written in php that wraps the SQLite database library.

To use the JSON1 SQLite extension, you need to compile the extension as a stand-alone loadable library, and use the `load_extension()` SQL function to load the extension at runtime.

```
$db = new SQLite3('mysqlitedb.db');
$db->exec('load_extension('json1.dll');');
```

or, you can just call it from php like this:

```
$db = new SQLite3('mysqlitedb.db');
$db->loadExtension('json1.dll');
```

It appears that you already know how to compile a C source file, so I won't go into that.

**EDIT** My mistake.

To compile the json extension , use

```
gcc -g -shared json1.c sqlite3ext.h -o json1.dll
```

and make sure that both the `json1.c` and `sqlite3ext.h` files are in the same directory. I'm assuming from your example that you are using a Windows compatible GNU compiler (MinGW, or something).

Comment: So I don't need to replace `php_sqlite3.dll`? I should instead create a DLL containing only the JSON1 extension and then load that at PHP runtime by adding it to `php.ini`?

Comment: No, you simply call the `sqlite3::loadExtension` [link here](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.loadextension.php) function in php.

Comment: I'm struggling to work out how to make `json1.dll`.  I've found a `json1.c` on the SQLite website but when I try to compile it by doing `gcc -shared json1.c -o json1.dll` I get the error `json1.c:26:24: fatal error: sqlite3ext.h: No file or directory`.

Comment: Very well, I'll edit to show the compilation. However, you show that you are using gcc to compile, but you are creating a `.dll` file, not a `.so` file. Are you trying to do this for Linux or Windows?

Comment: I'm using Windows.

Comment: Now `gcc` succeeds but when I do `$db = new SQLite3('mysqlitedb.db');
$db->loadExtension('json1.dll');` it says `Warning: SQLite3::loadExtension(): SQLite Extension are disabled in C:\root\2018-02-07-sqlite_json1\json1.php on line 4`.

Comment: Yes I'm using MinGW.

Comment: Try specifying the `sqlite3.extension_dir` in php.ini, and placing the extension dll in that directory. Failing that, your build of `php_sqlite3.dll` doesn't support SQLite extension loading.

Comment: Different error now. I added `sqlite3.extension_dir = "ext"` to `php.ini` and now the error message is `Warning: SQLite3::loadExtension(): Unable to load extension at 'ext\json1.dll' in C:\root\2018-02-07-sqlite_json1\json1.php on line 4`

Comment: Ok, damn. But thanks anyway for your patience and all your help.